# How to combine rows containing same specific column value into one row using pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

suppose that this is my data:

person1 350
person1 450
person1 100
person2 200
person2 300
person3 500
person3 400

I want to get the average of the values of each person into one row so it becomes like this :
person1 300
person2 250
person3 450

how I can do this using Pandas on Python ?

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply groupby on the first column and then apply mean to it:

```
df.groupby('Name')['Value'].mean()
```

Answer (score 1):

Using this as your dataframe:

```
info = [['person1', 350], ['person1', 450], ['person1', 100], ['person2', 200], ['person2', 300], ['person3', 500], ['person3', 400]]
df = pd.DataFrame(info,columns=['Person', 'Amount'])
```

You can use groupby to group by 'Person' then take the mean of the 'Amount'.

```
df.groupby('Person')['Amount'].mean()
```